# Source node goes down what will happen in SymmetricDS?

Tags: postgresql, node-modules, open-source, symmetricds

If the 'Source' node gets down and the 'Target' nodes are up, can the 'Target' node does act as a 'Source' node in SymmetricDS for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2):

If data is synced unidirectionally from A (source) to B (target) then if the source is down, i.e. A then B needs to wait until A got back online

If data is synced bidirectionally such as both A and B are a source and a target, or, if A is synced unidirectionally from A (source of B) to B (target of A) and from B (source of C, target of A) to C (target of B) then if A is down B can continue working in its role of source either for A or for C

Comment: How can sync nodes bidirectionally? I have node A(source) and node B(target). I want to sent data to A from B.

Comment: By configuring database table triggers on both db servers and configuring routing from A to B and from B to A. An example is a retail system where prices are synced from the central location to stores and sales are synced from stores to the central location

Comment: Do you have any documentation for that sync nodes bidirectionally? I use SymmetricDS version 3.10 and PostgreSQL 12

Comment: Sure. Use the official documentation of your version of the tool